# Probability of at most 1 tail? Loaded Coin Probability

Tags: probability, statistics

If someone tosses a loaded coin 40 times and the probability of each toss resulting in a head is $\frac{1}{4}$, what is the probability that the person will get at most one tail?

The answer is supposed to be $(\frac{1}{4})^{40}+(\frac{1}{4})^{39}(\frac{3}{4})\cdot 40$, however, I don't understand how this is computed.

I'm guessing the words "at most" are important to the computations, but I can't find what they are supposed to affect in terms of any formulas that may apply.  Is this conditional probability?

I think maybe the two events are "exclusive or," which is why we add the probabilities together.  So if the second part, $(\frac{1}{4})^{39}(\frac{3}{4})\cdot 40$, is the probability of at most one tail, why do we multiply the probability of a tail on each of the 40 tosses by the probability of a head on each of the 40 tosses *and* the 40 ways in which it could be arranged?

Thank you in advance to anyone who can offer some help/explanation!

Comment: look up Bernoulli trials: $P(k) = \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$ where k is desired outcome and n is number of trials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they get 0 tails, that means they got heads 40 consecutive times.  The probability of that happening is $( \frac {1} {4})^{40}$.

If they get exactly 1 tail and 39 heads that's: $( \frac {1} {4})^{39} \cdot ( \frac 3 4 ) \cdot 40$  The $( \frac {1} {4})^{39}$ part is from the 39 heads the $( \frac 3 4 )$ is from the tail and the $40$ is because there are $40$ different places the one tail could occur.

Adding those together, the probability of exactly zero tails and the probability of exactly one tail, we get:

$( \frac {1} {4})^{40} + ( \frac {1} {4})^{39} \cdot ( \frac 3 4 ) \cdot 40$

You could also look up binomial distributions to learn more about problems like these.

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful!  Would it be correct to think of it as we add the probability of exactly zero tails and the probability of exactly one tail together because those are the only two outcomes given you can't get 1/2 of a tail?   Lol.  Is it therefore the union of the event in which you get 0 tails and the event in which you get 1 tail?  Might be an obvious question, but I'm trying to make sure I fully understand the reasoning behind these types of problems.

Comment: That's exactly it!

Comment: Great, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

look up Bernoulli trials: $P(k) = \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$ where k is desired outcome and n is number of trials

you have that

> - n = 40
> - k = 1
> - p = $\frac{1}{4}$

therefore P(1 Tail) + P(no tails) $= \binom{40}{1}(\frac{1}{4})^{39}(\frac{3}{4})^{1} + (\frac{1}{4})^{40}$

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I think I understand your point about Bernoulli trials (though I hadn't come across that term and formula before), but I don't understand how your answer works out to be correct?  Isn't 40 choose 1 equal to 40!/!=40!?

Comment: If we were going to think of it in terms of coefficients, why wouldn't we use the Multinomial Coefficient, i.e. 40!/(1!*39!)?  I'm not doing so well with this material, so I'm assuming you are correct in your answer, but would like to know what I'm missing :)

Comment: the multinomial coefficient is the computation of that representation (combinations) so yes you are correct in the computation of that